# Parsing subnode with TouchXML

Tags: objective-c, xml, touchxml

I'm using TouchXML to parse my RSS.
 **The new XML**

```
 <channel>
 <item> 
 <title> </title>
  <social>
   <views>
    <total_views>2</total_views>
   </views>
   <reviews>
    <average_rating>2</average_rating>
   </reviews>
  </social>
 </item>
 </channel>
```

I currently parsing the XML and passing it with `initWithData` to my detail view for the title of the article like this:

```
 [rssData objectForKey: @"title" ];
```

But how do I show the value of stars its a subnode of rate and rate is a subnode from social?

I have tried this: `[rssData objectForKey: @"social/rate/stars" ];`

But it won't work. Please tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

The entire premise that I based my original answers seem to be wrong. If you've used the following snippet,

```
for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    int counter;
    for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
        //  common procedure: dictionary with keys/values from XML node
        [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];
    }

    [results addObject:item];
    [item release];
}
```

to generate your code than children of `social` element are stored as a string value and any reasonable means to extract them are lost. I would suggest that you store the nodes rather than go about creating the dictionary. Here's the example of extracting the rating,

```
NSString * xmlString = @"<channel> <item> <title> </title> <social> <views> <total_views>2</total_views> </views> <reviews> <average_rating>2</average_rating> </reviews> </social> </item> </channel>";

CXMLDocument * xmlDocument = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlString options:0 error:nil] autorelease];
NSArray * nodes = [xmlDocument nodesForXPath:@"//item" error:nil];

for (CXMLElement * node in nodes) {

    NSString * title = [[node nodeForXPath:@"title" error:nil] stringValue];
    NSString * average_rating = [[node nodeForXPath:@"social/reviews/average_rating" error:nil] stringValue] ;
    NSLog(@"%@", title);
    NSLog(@"%@", average_rating);
}
```

Comment: :79: warning: 'NSDictionary' may not respond to '-nodesForXPath:error:'

Comment: Assumed it was a node. Since it is an dictionary, you can use `valueForKeyPath:` to get the value. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSCFString 0x6370510> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key reviews.'

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSCFString 0x6370510> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key reviews.'

Comment: Is this from the same XML that you've presented? I don't see the key `reviews`.

Comment: No the new XML is:   <channel>  <item> <social> <reviews> <average_rating>. But the Social node has 2 childs. One of them is Reviews.

Comment: Can you add a sample of this XML to the question? It will give me a clearer picture as to what the key path should be.

Comment: I have added a XML example to your answer.

Comment: <channel>
 <item> 
 <title> </title>
  <social>
   <views>
    <total_views>2</total_views>
   </views>
   <reviews>
    <average_rating>2</average_rating>
   </reviews>
  </social>
</item>
</channel>

Comment: And the key path that you used was @"social.reviews.average_rating"? Did that give you an error? If so, how are you getting `rssData`?

Comment: ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CXMLElement nodeForXPath:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9364c0'

Comment: 79: warning: 'CXMLElement' may not respond to '-nodeForXPath:error:'

Answer (score 0):

try this , you need to pass readNode value like "channle", and it will return array, including child subnode

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)parseNodeFromXML:(NSString *)strXML readForNode:(NSString *)strReadValue
    {
        NSError *theError = NULL;
        CXMLDocument *theXMLDocument = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:strXML options:0 error:&theError] ;

        NSMutableArray *arrReturn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *nodes = [[theXMLDocument rootElement] nodesForXPath:strReadValue error:nil];

        for (CXMLNode *itemNode in nodes)
        {

            NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            // PROCESS FOR READ ELEMENT ATTRIBUTES IN CURRENT NODE -------------------------

            if([itemNode isMemberOfClass:[CXMLElement class]]){
                CXMLElement *elements=(CXMLElement*)itemNode;
                NSArray *arAttr=[elements attributes];

                for (int i=0; i<[arAttr count]; i++) {
                    if([[arAttr objectAtIndex:i] name] && [[arAttr objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]){
                        [dic setValue:[[arAttr objectAtIndex:i] stringValue] forKey:[[arAttr objectAtIndex:i] name]];
                    }
                }
            }


            // PROCESS FOR READ CHILD NODE IN CURRENT NODE -------------------------

            for (CXMLNode *childNode in [itemNode children])
            {
                //   NSLog(@"count -- %d ---  %@",[childNode childCount],[childNode children]);

                // IF ANY CHILD NODE HAVE MULTIPLE CHILDRENS THEN DO THIS....- 
                if ([childNode childCount] > 1)
                {
                    NSMutableDictionary *dicChild = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    for (CXMLNode *ChildItemNode in [childNode children])
                    {
                        [dicChild setValue:[ChildItemNode stringValue] forKey:[ChildItemNode name]];
                    }
                     [dic setValue:dicChild forKey:[childNode name]];
                }else
                {
                    [dic setValue:[childNode stringValue] forKey:[childNode name]];
                }

            }

            [arrReturn addObject:dic];
        }

        //    NSLog(@"%@",arrReturn);
        return arrReturn;
    }
```